# A limit without using l'Hôpital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits

I attempted many times to solve this limit (conjugates, ...), but I always get lost when the expression gets too large for me
$$\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{x-2}{\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{x+7}-6}$$
I appreciate any help.

Comment: One way to keep the computation to a manageable size is by tackling the limit of the reciprocal.  The denominator now becomes a numerator, and we can conveniently group the terms so that we have three limits that can be resolved using *conjugates*.

Comment: DigitalGambler, what did you try in order to solve your exercise ? Read [this thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and learn how to ask a good question on this site. Your post is being closed because it is a very low-quality question.

Comment: Perhaps the group could give a relatively new contributor more of an opportunity to take feedback and revise before closing.

Comment: Hint: In many of these cases you can "guess" the right answer and then use some of the algebraic manipulations to prove it.  These usually do NOT need formal $N$ and $epsilon$ arguments unless you are seeking a very high level of rigor.

Comment: @digitalGambler I'm afraid Angelo is right. I shouldn't have answered your question. Please, try to ask better questions in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $$\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{x-2}{\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{x+7}-6}=\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{1}{\frac{\sqrt{x-1}-1}{x-2}+\frac{\sqrt{x+2}-2}{x-2}+\frac{\sqrt{x+7}-3}{x-2}}$$

Comment: You should not answer very low-quality questions.

Comment: what is the matter with you @Angelo, can't you be a little friendly with the newbies like me

Comment: @digitalGambler, just read [this thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and learn how to ask a good question on this site. Your post is being closed because you do not respect the rules of this site. Moreover, you should learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in order to write formulas in an appropriate manner.

Comment: thank you @Angelo, I appreciate any help.

Comment: @digitalGambler I'm afraid Angelo is right. I shouldn't have answered your question. Please, try to ask better questions in the future.